# React how to update props for item clicked and not all items

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm having an issue updating a value in React. I will also preface that I am a noob at react and still trying to grasp some concepts.

I have a component that increments and decrements a value when clicked.  The issue is that it updates all props for all items instead of the one clicked.

For instance I have a list of items, I click on 1 item to update `quantity` which it does but also updates the quantity of the other items as well.  All these items are similar.  What also needs to be done is it should count all quantity from all items and output a total which doesn't work either.

This is an image with annotations on what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/HlhPcym.png]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Quantity Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import If from '../utils/helpers';


var QuantityInput = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(props) {
    return {
      quantity: this.props.quantity
    };
  },

  handleIncrement: function(e) {
    this.props.handleIncrement(this.props.quantity + 1);
  },

  handleDecrement: function(e) {
    if (this.props.quantity > 1) {
      this.props.handleDecrement(this.props.quantity - 1);
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.props.quantity
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="quantity-input">
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</span>
        <div className="quantity" onChange={this.handleChange}>{this.props.quantity}</div>
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = QuantityInput;
```

Products:

```
import React from 'react';
import If from '../utils/helpers';
import QuantityInput from '../components/quantity.js'


var Product = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  handleIncrement: function(e) {
    this.setState({
      quantity: this.state.quantity + 1
    });
  },

  handleDecrement: function(e) {
    if (this.state.quantity > 1) {
      this.setState({
        quantity: this.state.quantity - 1
      });
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    var value = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');

    value = (value == '' ? 1 : value);
    value = parseInt(value);

    this.setState({
      quantity: value
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    var content;
    var self = this;
    if (this.props.items.length > 0) {
      this.props.items.map(function(product) {
        var items = product.priceCode.map(function(priceCode) {
          return (
            <div className="list-item" key={priceCode.priceCode_id}>
              <div className="list-info list-info--cart">
                <div className="list-info__venue">
                  <h3 className="event-title">{priceCode.priceCode_title}</h3>
                  <If condition={priceCode.priceCode_passcode}>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Passcode" />
                  </If>
                  <span className="event-details">{priceCode.priceCode_info}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="controls">
                <div className="list-info__price">${priceCode.priceCode_price}</div>
                <QuantityInput quantity={self.state.quantity} handleChange={self.handleChange} handleIncrement={self.handleIncrement} handleDecrement={self.handleDecrement} />
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        });

        content = {items}
      });
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var ProductContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  componentWillMount: function() {
    this.loadProducts(this.props.url);
  },

  loadProducts: function(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        this.setState({
          data: data
        });
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err, data) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },

  _hasData: function() {
    var displayedItems = this.state.data.filter(function(product) {
      var match = product.priceCode.filter(function(priceCode) {
        return priceCode.priceCode_title.toLowerCase();
      });

      return (match !== -1);
    }.bind(this));

    return (
      <div>
        <Product items={displayedItems} />
      </div>
    ); 
  }, 

  render: function() {
    if (this.state.data) {
      return (
        <div className="price-code">
          {this._hasData()}
          <div className="subtotal-wrapper">
            <a href="#" className="button button--gray">Clear Selections</a>
            <div className="subtotal">
              Subtotal ({this.state.quantity}):
            </div>
            <a href="#" className="button">Find Tickets</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      )          
    } else {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return false
  }
});

module.exports = ProductContainer;
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the UI you want to render ? A screenshot or something ?

Comment: Sure, this is the image with some annotations on what should happen [http://i.imgur.com/HlhPcym.png](http://i.imgur.com/HlhPcym.png)

Comment: Thanks ! It's a lot clearer now. Could you update your question with this image ? Since I'm going to based my response on this image, it will be more clear for everyone :)

Comment: Done, check question.  Thanks

Comment: Ok that's my answer, do not hesitate to tell me if something is not clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `QuantityInput` components will each receive the same `quantity` since you're passing them the `Product` component `quantity` state.

By the way, you make no distinction between each `quantity`, it's very confusing. That's one way of doing it :

I will not create a detailed implementation but here is the main points (the `[...]` indicates that you're code is left unchanged):

*ProductContainer*

```
var ProductContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      data: [],
      subTotal: 0
    }
  },

  incrementSubTotal: function() {
    this.setState({
        data: this.state.data,
        subTotal: this.state.subTotal + 1
    });
  },

  decrementSubTotal: function() {
    this.setState({
        data: this.state.data,
        subTotal: this.state.subTotal - 1
    });
  },

  _hasData: function() {
    [...]

    return (
      <div>
        <Product 
            items={displayedItems}
            incrementSubTotal={this.incrementSubTotal}
            decrementSubTotal={this.decrementSubTotal}/>
      </div>
    ); 
  }, 

  render: function() {
    [...]
       Subtotal ({this.state.subTotal}):
    [...]
  }
});
```

*Product*

```
var Product = React.createClass({
  //this component is now stateless

  render: function() {
    [...]

    // the following extract items from within this.props and lets the 'incrementSubTotal' and
    // 'decrementSubTotal' in '...callbacks'. See http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html
    // for details.
    var {items, ...callbacks} = this.props;
    [...]
        <QuantityInput {...callbacks}/>
    [...]

    return (
      <div>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

*QuantityInput*

```
var QuantityInput = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      quantity: 0
    }
  },

  handleIncrement: function(e) {
    [...]
    this.props.incrementSubTotal();
  },

  handleDecrement: function(e) {
    [...]
    this.props.decrementSubTotal();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="quantity-input">
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleDecrement}>-</span>
        <div className="quantity">{this.state.quantity}</div>
        <span className="button button--gray controls__quantity" onClick={this.handleIncrement}>+</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

As you can see I'm passing callbacks to update the state of the Parent component from within child components. **It's not a very good practice** here. A better approach would be to keep the state of all you inputs on the top level component, acting as a "controller-view" component if you know a little about MVC model.
When clicking the "+" or "-" buttons, your application should triggers a event to let the ProductContainer knows that something has changed and it has to update it's state. And it's exactly the role of a the (Flux)[https://facebook.github.io/flux/] architecture and you should definitively take a look a it :)

Comment: Wow thank you for the detailed enough example!  Also thanks for the suggestions on a better way to do things!

Comment: You're welcome :) If you decide to try Flux, maybe this another answer could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28060493/react-flux-and-xhr-routing-caching/32224104#32224104

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out!  I do have one question though, I read the post you referenced but I want to make sure I understand it.  `{...callbacks}` should be followed by me putting in all the methods I am trying to access correct, like `handleIncrement` etc and keep those on the actual `<QuantityInput {...callbacks}/>` or do I just pass those in the `var` definition and leave the component call alone with just `{...callbacks}`?  I've tried both but keep getting `this.props...` is not a function

Comment: For this part you have to write it exactly as I wrote it. It's a JSX shortcut, you can learn more here : http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html
Please note also that I do not test the actual code that I have posted, it may be containing some typo or other errors, it's just to let you get the idea :)

Comment: Ahh ok, yea I read it but was confused.  Had to read it a few more times :).  Haha ok thanks for the heads up, hopefully I should be able to figure it out from here.  Thanks again.